# How to display the specific post content by using POST ID

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I'm trying to create a plugin that display the specific post content by using POST ID.

**example:**

`[post id="2"]`

But I don't know how to send POST ID from function to **$my_postid** below are my code

```
function post_function($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
   'id' => 21504,
   ), $atts));

 //getting post content
 $my_postid = 21504;//This is page id or post id

$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

return $content;
}
add_shortcode('post', 'post_function');`
```

Comment: The way [`extract()`](https://secure.php.net/extract) works, you should be able to use it via `$id` (because that is the key of the array). However, this is usually not recommended. [The official docu](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/#complete-example) uses an array as return element, and then access it via that array

Comment: @kero it might be worth adding your comment with a bit more detail for an answer so this question doesn't go unanswered. OP you can also answer your own question so that it shows up as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

First up, I'd suggest not using `extract()`. It makes it harder to tell exactly what the available variables are and how they're set, which is part of the confusion here. Instead, just use `$atts` directly. When you do that, any attributes you pass can be accessed on the `$atts` array like this:

```
$id = $atts['id'];
```

Use `shortcode_atts()` to ensure that the accepted attributes have default values so that you don't get an error if the user doesn't set the `id` on the shortcode.

When you use that approach your shortcode would look like this:

```
<?php
function post_function( $atts ) {
    // Set defaults for attributes.
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 21504,
    ), $atts );

    // Get the ID attribute.
    $post_id = $atts['id'];

    // Get post by ID.
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    // Check there is a post with that ID. If so, return the content, with filters applied.
    if ( $post ) {
        $content = $post->post_content;

        return apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'post', 'post_function' );
```